# What's the best way to determine if a Visual Studio project file is using the legacy format or the new .NET Core format?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have an operation that I want to run against my project files to normalize the order of the XML tags in them (to make it easier to see what has changed in version control without all those false positives caused by Visual Studio reordering the tags), but only for the ones in the legacy format - it will break project files that are in the new format. What's the best way to determine if a project file is using the legacy format or the new format? I was thinking I could search for an `Sdk` attribute on the root `Project` tag, and take that as a sign of the new format, but I don't know if all new format project files have that attribute or if it's guaranteed that old format project files won't...

Comment: Best to try to identify the old format, you don't know what the new format is going to turn into some day.  Pretty unlikely that the "ToolsVersion" attribute will ever come back.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of:

1. Look for markers indicating an SDK style project:

   - As you described, `<Project Sdk="..." />` is one way.
   - It's also possible to [import the SDK props/targets manually](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1400), for greater granularity.  So you probably also need to check if any `<Import ... Sdk="..." />` exist

```
<Project>
  <user prop here>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk/1.0.0.0" />
...
  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk/1.0.0.0" />
  <user target here>
</Project>
```

2. Look for markers that indicate a non-SDK project.  Several properties were deprecated or replaced, so you could look for the existence of some of these:

```
<!-- this is now part of the SDK, so only a non-SDK project would import it without a warning.  However, this wasn't in projects by default until VS2017 I think -->
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
<!-- This is also brought in by the SDK now, and might be a more reliable indicator -->
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- this property is deprecated -->
  <ProjectGuid>...</ProjectGuid>

  <!-- in SDK-style, this is replaced by <TargetFramework> -->
  <TargetFrameworkVersion>...</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```